# Windows command line to do 'Edit' action?

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, powershell, cmd.exe

The `start` command (in PowerShell an alias for `Start-Process`, in `cmd.exe` a shell builtin) does the same as the Windows Explorer context menu 'Open' action: it opens the file using the application which Windows has registered for it.

(Or are there perhaps small differences?  Or perhaps it triggers the default action, which normally is the 'Open' action?)

How do I trigger the 'Edit' action for a file from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Edit"-verb really does trigger the "Edit"-action.
(I tested it with changing the "Edit" for `.reg` files in the registry and running the command.)

Since you made your answer *"a partial answer"* did you want to know how you would do this in `cmd.exe`? I don't think it can be done natively in `cmd.exe'.

There is of course [ShelExec](http://www.naughter.com/shelexec.html).

But you can also run `powershell -command "start -verb edit textfile.txt"` in `cmd.exe`.

You can even put this in a shortcut with `doskey` like this:

```
doskey cmdedit=powershell -command "start -verb edit $1"
```

Now you can do `cmdedit textfile.txt` on the `cmd.exe`-prompt.

Note: for the doskey-'macro' to be available after restarting the computer/cmd-session you need to add this command in your startup-scripts. You can look [here](http://devblog.point2.com/2010/05/14/setup-persistent-aliases-macros-in-windows-command-prompt-cmd-exe-using-doskey/) for some suggestions to making it permanent.
I would go for the option of putting it in
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`.

---

**Edit:**

This `.reg` file does it all for you:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"AutoRun"="doskey cmdedit=powershell -command \"start -verb edit $1\""
```

Answer (score 3):

*(Partial answer which I discovered as I was typing the question.)*

For PowerShell I discovered the following:

```
start -verb edit ...filename...
```

Documentation (from `get-help start-process -full`):

```
-Verb <string>
    Specifies a verb to be used when starting the process, such as Edit, Open, or Print.
```